# Strip strings and date, time from mixed string with numbers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, data-cleaning

I have this kind of dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
            '355395.7037', 
            '355369.6383', 
            '355367.881', 
            '355381.419',
            '357394.9D7a82te7o6fm4o9n4t3h7 print: 06/10/202',
            '357405.7897626596'])

y = np.array([
            '4521429.292', 
            '4521430.0229', 
            ' 4521430.1191', 
            '4521430.1256',
            '3 13:36 4521735.552137422',
            '4521512.725'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':x, 'Y':y})
```

So, sometimes, I may have strings mixed with numbers.

> **A Solution I thought.**

If you note `357394.9D7a82te7o5fm4o9n4t3h7 print: 06/10/202` for example, there are the words `Date of month` inside number `357394.97827649437`.

and at `y` column : `'3 13:36 4521735.552137422'` there is the `3` that came from `2023` from previous `print: 06/10/202` and the time `13:36`.

I want to get rid of them in order to have only the numbers.

I may have different situations like:

`'357394.9D7a82te7o6fm4o9n4t3h7 print: 06/10/2023'`

`13:36 4521735.552137422` for example.

Or,

`'357394.9 D7a82te7o6fm4o9n4t3h7 print: ',`

`'06/10/2023 13:36 4521735.552137422'`

If you see the numbers, for `X` column for example, all numbers have `6` digits before the decimal point, so we could take for example, the first 6 digits from

`'357394.9D7a82te7o6fm4o9n4t3h7 print: 06/10/202',` -> 357394 and apply decimal point and fill with the rest numbers until a white space or a word (print) exists. So, the number to take is `357394.97827649437`

But the thing is that we have a string and we cannot apply for example `float` or `int` to process it.

For the second case, for `Y` column:

`'3 13:36 4521735.552137422',`

I think we must search from the end and when we see a decimal point, count `7` digits (Y columns has 7 digits before decimal) and stop there.

** UPD **

If we use:

```
x = np.array([
            '355395.7037', 
            '355369.6383', 
            '355367.881', 
            '355381.419',
            '357394.9D7a82te7o6fm4o9n4t3h7 p',
            '357405.7897626596'])

y = np.array([
            '4521429.292', 
            '4521430.0229', 
            '4521430.1191', 
            '4521430.1256',
            'rint: 06/10/2023 13:36 4521735.552137422',
            '4521512.725'])
```

then the solution gives:

```
                    X             Y
0         355395.7037   4521429.292
1         355369.6383  4521430.0229
2          355367.881  4521430.1191
3          355381.419  4521430.1256
4  357394.97827649437      06102023
5   357405.7897626596   4521512.725
```

where the `Y` values is:  `06102023` instead of `4521735.552137422`

Comment: Do you know how the data was created? It does look like the output of a program where several processes or threads write into the same file without proper synchronization. If so, the `3` out of `print: 06/10/202` could be anywhere within the following numbers. You might want to check for outliers after removing the strings that you will be able to recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to try avoiding this format in the first place, especially if numbers get mixed with your value.

That said, you could try to get rid of letters with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), and then to use a regex to [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the number:

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace('[^\d .]+', '', regex=True)
                          .str.extract(r'(\d{6,}(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=False))
```

For a dynamic solution to specify the number of digits per column:

```
d = {'X': 6, 'Y': 7}

out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace('[^\d .]+', '', regex=True)
                          .str.extract(fr'(\d{{{d[s.name]},}}(?:\.\d+)?)',
                                       expand=False)
              )
```

Output:

```
                    X                  Y
0         355395.7037        4521429.292
1         355369.6383       4521430.0229
2          355367.881       4521430.1191
3          355381.419       4521430.1256
4  357394.97827649437  4521735.552137422
5   357405.7897626596        4521512.725
```

##### updated example:

Just avoid removing the date separator:

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace('[^\d ./]+', '', regex=True)
                          .str.extract(r'(\d{6,}(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=False))
```

Or only remove letters:

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace('[a-zA-Z]+', '', regex=True)
                          .str.extract(r'(\d{6,}(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=False))
```

Output:

```
                    X                  Y
0         355395.7037        4521429.292
1         355369.6383       4521430.0229
2          355367.881       4521430.1191
3          355381.419       4521430.1256
4  357394.97827649437  4521735.552137422
5   357405.7897626596        4521512.725
```

Comment: Hi, nice solution. The thing is that for the `X` column, we receive : `357394.9` instead of `357394.97827649437`

Comment: @George I just updated the answer. Note that is is not a bullet proof approach and if you have incorrect digits mixed with your real number, there is no way to solve this. Better fix this at the source.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I updated the the end the post. If we change `X` to `'357394.9D7a82te7o6fm4o9n4t3h7 p'` and `Y` to `rint: 06/10/2023 13:36 4521735.552137422'`, then the `Y` values is wrong.

Comment: @George then only exclude letters.

Comment: It's a bit sad that you unaccept the answer while I hadn't time to comment, this is virtually the same as I suggested with a minor variation…

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I upvoted the other answer and it seems that accidentally I clicked on accept also! Just logged in and saw it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that non-numeric chars can be "injected" in both(or either) in integer and fractional parts of a float number, use the following `extract + replace` processing:

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.extract(r'([a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+)', 
                                       expand=False, flags=re.I)
               .str.replace(r'[^\d.]+', '', regex=True))
print(out)
```

---

```
                    X                  Y
0         355395.7037        4521429.292
1         355369.6383       4521430.0229
2          355367.881       4521430.1191
3          355381.419       4521430.1256
4  357394.97827649437  4521735.552137422
5   357405.7897626596        4521512.725
```

Comment: Nice solution! It works with different senarios also!

Comment: This wouldn't work if there is any dot before the actual number, for instance `'a.b 355395.7037'`

Comment: @mozway, this solution assumes that a string contains a single entry in format `[a-z\d]+\.[a-z\d]+`

Comment: Hi, I upvoted and it seems that I accidentally accepted your answer.Since, the previous answer was first I accepted that. I hope it is no big deal, sorry.